# Variable assignment and manipulation in Python

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I am pretty confused with the difference in results of the Python codes below. Why in first case "a" does not change upon the change of "b", but in second one does?

```
a=b=[]
b = [1,2,3]
print b,a
########## compare with below ################################
a=b=[]
b.append([1,2,3])
print b,a
```

Result of first part is:
[1,2,3] [ ]
and result of the second part is:
[[1,2,3]] [[1,2,3]]

It was suggested that it is a duplicate question but I think here I am changing the list "b" with two different ways and I guess it could show how these two methods of variable manipulation could be different.

Comment: In the first part you are pointing b at a new, different list.  In the 2nd a and b both point to the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the other answers, this is straight from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
list.append(x)
    Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].
```

Looking at:

```
a[len(a):] = [x]
```

it is easy to see that using append is modifying the original list (`a` in the python sample code, `b` in your case).

As the others people have pointed out, using an assignment statement is assigning a new value to `b`, instead of modifying it via `append`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `=` is not the same as `append`.

When you do `b = [1, 2, 3]`, you assign a new value to `b`.  This does not involve the old value of `b` in any way; you can do this no matter what value `b` held before.

When you do `b.append(...)`, you *modify* the object that is the existing value of `b`.  If that object is also the value of other names (in this case, `a`), then those names will also "see" the change.  Note that, unlike assignment, these types of operations depend on what kind of value you have.  You can do `b.append(...)` because `b` is a list.  If `b` was, say, an integer, you could not do `b.append`, but you could still do `b = [1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are reassigning the variable `b`, and now it points to another list.

```
a = b = [] # a -> [] <- b
b = [1, 2, 3] # a -> [], b -> [1, 2, 3]
```

In the second example, both `a` and `b` variables are pointing to the same list, and you are inserting values in the list:

```
a = b = [] # a -> [] <- b
b.append([1, 2, 3]) # a -> [[1, 2, 3]] <- b
```